# SNMPd: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci

Tags: c, cross-compiling, snmp, powerpc, net-snmp

I cross-compiled NET-SNMP 5.7.1 from sources to a PowerPC using ELDK-3.1.
When I try to load the `snmpd` daemon in my embedded board, I see the message:

```
# snmpd -f -Lo
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
pcilib: Cannot find any working access method.
```

Of course my PPC board has no PCI, and I wonder why is netsnmp looking for it.

In more than one place I see this same message ([sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1328889180.7889.YahooMailNeo@web29009.mail.ird.yahoo.com&forum_name=net-snmp-users), [mail-archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/net-snmp-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg29199.html), [google-groups](https://groups.google.com/group/mailing.unix.net-snmp-users/browse_thread/thread/e355bd373b3babf1/f0f12ea4e7dd82f9?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Cannot%20open%20/proc/bus/pci#f0f12ea4e7dd82f9)), but ir has no answer at all. Another variant, with a little but unhelpful responses at ([archlinuxarm](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1989&p=10843)).

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on a Linux target.

Net-SNMP's changelog lists "[PATCH 3057093]: allow linux to use libpci for creating useful ifDescr strings".

The configure script will search for an available libpci, and, having found one, will define 
`HAVE_PCI_LOOKUP_NAME` and `HAVE_PCI_PCI_H`. To disable this code: after configuring, you can change those defines in `include/net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h`, then rebuild. The affected code is in `agent/mibgroup/if-mib/data_access/interface_linux.c`.

Comment: I've already tried it, but, strangely, with no success. Maybe I messed something, so I'll give it a new try and come back soon to tell. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Changing `net-snmp-config.h.in` does not work, but doing exactly as you said and changing `net-snmp-config.h` _after_ configure works. My scripts were broken and were calling `configure` again with no need, so my changes were lost. Now `snmpd` loads with no error. Thanks again!

Comment: As net-snm-config.h will generated - how to patch net-snmp-config.h.in to achieve same result?

Answer (score 1):

There's also a patch in this bug report: http://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2449/

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue using the stock `snmpd` that comes with the Raspbian.

In `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` file I isolated the issue to the following line

`agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161`

Instead of listening on all interfaces, if I specify the the ip address of the `eth0` interface i.e.:

`agentAddress udp:10.0.1.5:161,udp6:[::1]:161`

Then `snmpd` starts fine.

My speculation is that the stock `snmpd` tries to enumerate all possible interfaces including the pci ones.