# SNMP on BeagleBone Black

Tags: linux, net-snmp, pci

I am attempting to implement the net-snmp libraries on the Beaglebone Black running Angstrom. When I install the net-snmp packet in the repo, or I attempt to install net-snmp from source, I get the following error when attempting to start snmpd.

```
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
pcilib: Cannot find any working access method.
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470494/snmpd-cannot-open-proc-bus-pci), but to no avail. Following the steps that answer provides does not work.

Can anyone tell me how to install the net-snmp libraries on the Beaglebone and configure them so that they work? Either using the angstrom repo package or installing from source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this website](http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/08/compiling-and-installing-net-snmp-for-beaglebone/)

This worked for me but I still don´t know what --enable-mini-agent is for and I can't start agentx. I'll edit the answer if I find out how to do it.

Comment: What I ended up doing is to install the net-snmp libraries from source found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.2/). I then used a patch (found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/_discuss/thread/193dc0ef/7eb3/attachment/ifmib.patch)) to fix the errors it was having with angstrom. Steps: 1. ./configure the source 2. Move patch to net-snmp source directory and patch using "patch -p1 < ifmib.patch" 3. make 4. make install

Comment: I did a similar thing, but I used the Yocto project to compile and create an installable package. The error with pcilib is not worrying, but you will have to install pcilib even if your device doesn't have a pci bus.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beagleboard/M6oxGdKDYWg/U4p7wO3mYDMJ This would help, at the end it has been mentioned to take 'bitbake net-smnp' and it built: http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/?pkgsearch=net-snmp

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker