# How do I build my OID tree under my PEN instead of an extension of Net-SNMP?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Currently, my OIDs branch from Net-SNMP using `extend`, which results in an OID like this:

`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.8072.1.3.2.4.1.2.1.49.1258`

or without the MIB:

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.4.1.2.1.49.1258`

8072 is Net-SNMP,
49 is the decimal value of an ASCII "1" (an arbitrary name I gave my extension), and
1258 is a 'leaf' on my root OID (49).

Now that I have a [PEN](https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page), **how do I go about making my OID tree under my PEN** so that I can execute an `snmpwalk` that displays:

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.<MyPEN>.<MyOIDTree>`

OS: Linux (Raspbian)

Comment: The last example you posted seems to be the way to go: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-liang-iana-pen-06.html.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Definitely. The question is how to use it.

Comment: Check this https://netbeez.net/blog/snmp/.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz That's for creating MIBs.

Comment: yes, that's what "OID tree" means to me, you want to build your own mib.

Comment: I need `.1.3.6.1.4.1.<MyPEN>.<MyOIDTree>` instead of `.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.4.1.2.1.49.1258`

Comment: [MIBs are OID](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/community/solarwinds-community/geek-speak/blog/2013/12/26/what-are-mibs-and-oids-how-to-manage-them) tree definitions:"OID or Object Identifier, is an identifier used to name and point to an object in the MIB hierarchy.".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172325/discussion-between-ctrl-s-and-luis-munoz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Partial Solutions:**

**-Good-**
Specify an OID in the `extend` command (in *[snmpd.conf](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html)*) like so:

`extend [OID] <extName> </dir/binary> </dir/script>`

The OID is optional, however, omitting it will cause the Net-SNMP PEN to be used by default.

In my case, my `extend` looks like this:

`extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.<myPEN> SQL /bin/sh /usr/sbin/MyScript.sh`

This produces the following output:

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.[PEN redacted].4.1.2.3.83.81.76.1258 = STRING: "My Data"`

This is much closer to the desired structure since it is now extending from a custom PEN, though one is now faced with trimming off the `.4.1.2.3` and the `.83.81.76` (resulting from the extension name 'SQL').

If anyone knows how to remove those, post it as a new answer!

**-Better-**
Use the `pass` command:
`pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN        /bin/sh       /home/pi/net-snmp/local/shellCode`
Shell code example: [passtest](https://github.com/winlibs/net-snmp/blob/master/local/passtest)

Output:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.1.0 = STRING: "Hello World!"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.2.1.2.1 = INTEGER: 9
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.2.1.3.1 = OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.99
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.3.0 = Timeticks: (363136200) 42 days, 0:42:42.00
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.4.0 = IpAddress: 127.0.0.1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.5.0 = Counter32: 9
.1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN.6.0 = Gauge32: 9
```

This appears to solve both issues, however I am unsure of the extent of its capabilities in comparison to a 'proper' OID tree installation.

**-Best- (Complete Solution)**
Register OIDs using a MIB...

Comment: Seems you can't get rid of those unless you write a custom MIB or a [perl extension](https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-System_Monitoring_Tools-Net-SNMP-Extending.html). For an explanation of what the numbers mean see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752081/oid-objects-after-pen-when-using-net-snmp-extend-in-snmpd-conf).

Comment: Yeah, I've discovered that the `extend` command is responsible for the '.4.1.2.3' after the PEN and cannot be removed. The custom MIB needs to extend from the SNMP agent in order for the tree to 'work correctly'. My MIBs are now understood by `snmptranslate`, I'm now working on getting my auto-generated C files recognized/installed so that I can see my OID tree when walking my IP address.

Comment: Great reference.  Thanks!  I will try that when I get a chance.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I followed your answer on the question you linked, and I've nearly got it to work except for one issue.  I can't seem to get my subagent to connect to the master agent.

Comment: How are you starting the subagent, remember that ports below 1024 are privileged ones so you have to pick one above that.

Comment: master agent as root: `sudo snmpd -f -Lo -C --rwcommunity=public --master=agentx --agentXSocket=tcp:localhost:1705`  
output: `pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
pcilib: Cannot find any working access method.
pcilib: pci_init failed
Turning on AgentX master support.
Error opening specified endpoint ""
Server Exiting with code 1`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471975/2834978) something about that. Seems something to do when compiling your subagent. Did not happen to me.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Saw that already, and when I went to make the changes, the PCI lines were already commented.  I don't know where else it could be getting that 'command' from...

Comment: Try starting the subagent first.

Comment: `Warning: Failed to connect to the agentx master agent (tcp:localhost:1705):`    
I assume this is because the master is not functioning properly.
This output repeats every 10 seconds or so until stopped by the user by pressing `Ctrl + C`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172985/discussion-between-luis-munoz-and-ctrl-s).