# OID objects after PEN when using Net-SNMP extend in snmpd.conf

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

Linux Net-SNMP agent can be extended using a PEN (private Enterprise Number) on /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf (`man snmpd.conf` for details)

```
# from the man page: extend [MIBOID] NAME PROG ARGS
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.32473 2 /tmp/snmp.sh
```

snmp.sh is a simple bash script that will echo the passed argument or current date otherwise with some weird exit codes

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1"
    exit 51
fi

/bin/date '+%F %T'

exit 37
```

Running `snmpwalk` on that OID

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 127.0.0.1 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473
```

Returns

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "/tmp/snmp.sh"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.3.1.50 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.4.1.50 = ""
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.5.1.50 = INTEGER: 5
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.6.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.7.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.20.1.50 = INTEGER: 4
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.21.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.3.1.1.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:53:44"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.3.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:53:44"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.3.1.3.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.3.1.4.1.50 = INTEGER: 37
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.4.1.2.1.50.1 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:53:44"
```

Trying to interpret the numbers
`32473` is the PEN reserved for examples and documentation that can be used locally for testing purposes
`50` is the decimal value of the ascii character `2`, the NAME.

Using `-Of` or`-Os` with `snmpwalk` or `snmptranslate` to provide an explanation of the tree does not work and output shows the plain numbers

```
snmptranslate -OS -Td SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.1.50
```

Result

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473.2.1.1.50
enterprises OBJECT-TYPE
-- FROM       SNMPv2-SMI
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) 32473 2 1 1 50 }
```

What the objects (numbers) after 32473 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those object numbers can be explained by comparing with the `snmpwalk` result of the another form of the `extend` option that does not use a PEN OID

```
extend 3 /tmp/snmp.sh 787878
```

Running a `snmpwalk`to get symbolic names

```
snmpwalk -c public -v 2c localhost NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects
```

Result:

```
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendNumEntries.0 = INTEGER: 1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendCommand."3" = STRING: /tmp/snmp.sh
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendArgs."3" = STRING: 787878
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendInput."3" = STRING:
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendCacheTime."3" = INTEGER: 5
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendExecType."3" = INTEGER: exec(1)
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendRunType."3" = INTEGER: run-on-read(1)
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendStorage."3" = INTEGER: permanent(4)
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendStatus."3" = INTEGER: active(1)
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."3" = STRING: 787878
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutputFull."3" = STRING: 787878
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutNumLines."3" = INTEGER: 1
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendResult."3" = INTEGER: 51
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutLine."3".1 = STRING: 787878
```

Adding `-On` to get the numeric output gives

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.2.1.51 = STRING: /tmp/snmp.sh
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.3.1.51 = STRING: 787878
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.4.1.51 = STRING: 
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.5.1.51 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.6.1.51 = INTEGER: exec(1)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.7.1.51 = INTEGER: run-on-read(1)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.20.1.51 = INTEGER: permanent(4)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.2.1.21.1.51 = INTEGER: active(1)
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.1.51 = STRING: 787878
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.2.1.51 = STRING: 787878
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.3.1.51 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.4.1.51 = INTEGER: 55
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.4.1.2.1.51.1 = STRING: 787878
```

The numeric output for the PEN exercise is

```
 snmpwalk -On -c public -v 2c 127.0.0.1 SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.32473

.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.1.0 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "/tmp/snmp.sh"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.3.1.50 = ""
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.4.1.50 = ""
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.5.1.50 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.6.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.7.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.20.1.50 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.2.1.21.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.3.1.1.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.3.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.3.1.3.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.3.1.4.1.50 = INTEGER: 33
.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.4.1.2.1.50.1 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
```

Now we can compare both exercises line by line by keeping the common part at the end and adding some convenience formatting

Ex1: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.     1.0 = INTEGER: 1`
Ex2: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.1.0 = INTEGER: 1`

Doing the same for all entries and comparing line by line:

```
nsExtendNumEntries   .1.0 = INTEGER: 1
nsExtendCommand      .2.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "/tmp/snmp.sh"
nsExtendArgs         .2.1.3.1.50 = ""
nsExtendInput        .3.2.1.4.1.50 = ""
nsExtendCacheTime    .2.1.5.1.50 = INTEGER: 5
nsExtendExecType     .2.1.6.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
nsExtendRunType      .2.1.7.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
nsExtendStorage      .2.1.20.1.50 = INTEGER: 4
nsExtendStatus       .2.1.21.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
nsExtendOutput1Line  .3.1.1.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
nsExtendOutputFull   .3.1.2.1.50 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
nsExtendOutNumLines  .3.1.3.1.50 = INTEGER: 1
nsExtendResult       .3.1.4.1.50 = INTEGER: 37
nsExtendOutLine      .4.1.2.1.50.1 = STRING: "2018-06-07 20:24:36"
```